Make a square table top with the minimal needed amount of straight cuts
inspired by : Make a square table top with six (or fewer) pieces
A carpenter has three pieces of beautiful wood, measuring 12 inches, 15 inches, and 16 inches square, respectively. They want to use them to make a small square table top 25 inches by 25 inches, using as few straight cuts as possible. How are they to do it?
Note: Cutting 2 pieces of wood with 1 cut (by stacking or lining up pieces, for example) is not allowed.
Additional remark/extra challenge: The intended solution cuts only triangles off the pieces of wood. However, it only matches Lezzup's answer in number of cuts.

Stacking is not allowed, but is lining up two pieces of wood allowed?

No, I guess that is not exactly the same, bet also not allowed

It can be done in

 4

(but not without 30 characters)

 


This is the kind of answer I was hoping to get/to be optimal.

Here is an answer with only

 5

straight cuts. See image below:

 
 Note that in the smallest square, the first cut is the vertical one :)


Another answer matching the current best number of cuts, but using only horizontal and vertical cuts (my brain doesn't work well with triangles).

 Made in 5 cuts. Cuts on the 15x15 square must be made in decreasing order of length (longest cuts first). 


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

For completeness: A suboptimal answer I had in mind was:

 

